# CatBoost with categorical features failed to work with Scikit-Learn CalibratedCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, catboost

I try to calibrate probability of `CatBoostClassifier` model using `sklearn` `CalibratedClassifierCV` . It is running well when fitting but failed when using calibrated model to predict. I already try to use `LGBMClassifier` because it has the same `categorical_features` and it is running well. Is there any solution for this issue? Here is code that I use:

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
import pandas as pd
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=3,n_redundant=0, random_state=42)
X=pd.DataFrame(X,columns=['a','b','c'])
X['d'] = [1,2,3,4,5]*20
model = CatBoostClassifier()
model.fit(X,y,verbose=False,cat_features=[3])
model_cat = CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=model,cv='prefit')
model_cat.fit(X,y)
model_cat.predict(X)

CatBoostError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3228/1832915274.py in <module>
----> 1 model_cat.predict(X)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in predict(self, X)
    383         """
    384         check_is_fitted(self)
--> 385         return self.classes_[np.argmax(self.predict_proba(X), axis=1)]
    386 
    387     def _more_tags(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in predict_proba(self, X)
    360         mean_proba = np.zeros((X.shape[0], len(self.classes_)))
    361         for calibrated_classifier in self.calibrated_classifiers_:
--> 362             proba = calibrated_classifier.predict_proba(X)
    363             mean_proba += proba
    364 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in predict_proba(self, X)
    637         n_classes = len(self.classes)
    638         pred_method = _get_prediction_method(self.base_estimator)
--> 639         predictions = _compute_predictions(pred_method, X, n_classes)
    640 
    641         label_encoder = LabelEncoder().fit(self.classes)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in _compute_predictions(pred_method, X, n_classes)
    499         (X.shape[0], 1).
    500     """
--> 501     predictions = pred_method(X=X)
    502     if hasattr(pred_method, '__name__'):
    503         method_name = pred_method.__name__

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/catboost/core.py in predict_proba(self, X, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose, task_type)
   4767                 with probability for every class for each object.
   4768         """
-> 4769         return self._predict(X, 'Probability', ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose, 'predict_proba', task_type)
   4770 
   4771 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/catboost/core.py in _predict(self, data, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose, parent_method_name, task_type)
   2175         if verbose is None:
   2176             verbose = False
-> 2177         data, data_is_single_object = self._process_predict_input_data(data, parent_method_name, thread_count)
   2178         self._validate_prediction_type(prediction_type)
   2179 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/catboost/core.py in _process_predict_input_data(self, data, parent_method_name, thread_count, label)
   2155         is_single_object = _is_data_single_object(data)
   2156         if not isinstance(data, Pool):
-> 2157             data = Pool(
   2158                 data=[data] if is_single_object else data,
   2159                 label=label,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/catboost/core.py in __init__(self, data, label, cat_features, text_features, embedding_features, column_description, pairs, delimiter, has_header, ignore_csv_quoting, weight, group_id, group_weight, subgroup_id, pairs_weight, baseline, feature_names, thread_count, log_cout, log_cerr)
    580                 elif isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
    581                     if (data.dtype.kind == 'f') and (cat_features is not None) and (len(cat_features) > 0):
--> 582                         raise CatBoostError(
    583                             "'data' is numpy array of floating point numerical type, it means no categorical features,"
    584                             " but 'cat_features' parameter specifies nonzero number of categorical features"

CatBoostError: 'data' is numpy array of floating point numerical type, it means no categorical features, but 'cat_features' parameter specifies nonzero number of categorical features
```

I don't know the issue comes from Scikit-Learn or CatBoost, but I already try to raise this is to CatBoost [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1849).

*Thanks for any respond. Will appreciate it so much.*

Comment: What are dtypes of the columns of "X" that you are passing to the model.fit() function?

Comment: In the example that I give above column a, b, and c are float and column d assume it is a categorical but already label encoder to be integer.

Comment: Then remove cat_features=[3] from model.fit()

Comment: No, I want to keep using cat_features to dealing with categorical features.

Comment: As you said as you have already label encoded it, you don't need to add that. If you want to add that parameter, don't label encode that feature as catboost automatically processes categorical features in your dataset.

Comment: No, you cannot handle a categorical features as integer just because it is already label encoder. If the features values are ordinal number than it makes sense, but if it is not, like colour and city, then you can't. Try to read more about how a model handle with categorical features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much to `catboost` and `scikit-learn` on  improving both modules performance and solve all raised issues. This issue solved by upgrading both `catboost` and `scikit-learn` to `1.x.x` version.